# How can i fix "access to protected services is denied." on my ios build in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

My ios build application gets the following error in console logs.
How can I fix this problem?

```
iPhone backboardd[34] : HID: The 'Passive' connection 'MyApplication' access to protected services is denied.
```

Comment: What piece of code produces that error?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog Hi this is not a piece of code it's a big project. I read somewhere this error and problem it's not about my code it's something happen in ios7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be [related to using a third party library without using the -ObjC flag](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/729938/error-the-passive-connection-appname-access-to-pro.html). You can add that flag with the build argument: `ios.objC=true`

Comment: Thanks a lot. i do it but nothing changed. There is still that error.

Comment: Does this cause a crash? From googling on this it seems that it is printed by apps but is mostly nothing.